if the character of a g-representation has real values then it is realizable over the reals

Prove or disprove that if the character of a G-representation (where G is a finite group) has real values (i.e. $\chi_{\phi}(g)\in\mathbb{R}\forall g\in G$) then it is realizable over the reals (i.e. there's a basis where the matrices of $\phi_g$ have real entries).

I think the statement is true, but I'm not sure how to prove it. I'm not sure which theorems from representation theory could be useful (e.g. maybe some properties of characters such as the fact that characters are class functions and $\overline{\chi_g} = \chi_{g^*}$).

It's hard to give a hint here! How much character theory do you know? Where is this quoted question from?

A hint would be to try looking for counterexamples among small groups.

Given an irreducible real representation $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$ there are three possibilities:

$V\cong U\otimes \mathbb{C}$, where $U$, is an irreducible representation over $\mathbb{R}$.
$V\ncong V^*$ and $V\oplus V^*\cong U\otimes \mathbb{C}$, where $U$, is an irreducible representation over $\mathbb{R}$.
$V\oplus V\cong U\otimes \mathbb{C}$, where $U$, is an irreducible representation over $\mathbb{R}$.

The first possibility corresponds to being realizable over the reals.  The second possibility corresponds to not having real values in the character.  Thus you are looking for any example of a representation falling into the third possibility.
As a hint for where to look first: The ring of endomorphisms for $U$ is $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{H}$, in possibilities $1,2,3$ respectively, so you are looking for a group associated with the quaternions.
Once you have found an irreducible representation of a group $G$, whose character $\chi$ is real, you can easily test if it is realisable over the reals:
For $g\in G$, let $\sqrt{g}$ be the number of square roots that $g$ has in $G$.  Then $$
\langle \chi,\sqrt{\,\,}\rangle=\begin{cases} 1, & \text{if the representation is realisable over the reals.}\\-1, & \text{if the representation is not realisable over the reals.}
\end{cases}
$$
If you are interested in why this works, the idea is as follows:

Let $V$ be the representation corresponding to $\chi$.
As $\chi$ is real, we have $\langle \chi^2,1\rangle =1$, so there is a $1$-dimensional space of maps $V\otimes V\to \mathbb{C}$. These are precisely the $G$-invariant bilinear forms on $V$.  Considering the decomposition $$V\otimes V= S^2(V)\oplus \Lambda^2(V),$$ we see that either there is a non-trivial symmetric bilinear form on $V$, or a non-trivial anti-symetric bilinear form on $V$.
At the level of characters this decomposition is:
$$\left\langle \chi(g)^2,1\right\rangle=\left\langle \frac{\chi(g)^2- \chi(g^2)}2,1\right\rangle + \left\langle \frac{\chi(g)^2+ \chi(g^2)}2,1\right\rangle,$$
so whether the form is symmetric or antisymmetric depends on whether $\langle \chi,\sqrt{\,\,}\rangle=1$ or $-1$.
If the representation $V$ is realisable over the reals, then we can define a $G$-invariant symmetric bilinear form on it by $(u,v)=\langle u,\bar{v}\rangle$ and we get $\langle \chi,\sqrt{\,\,}\rangle=1$.
Here $v\mapsto \bar{v}$ is taken with respect to the basis which realises $V$ over the reals, and $\langle,\rangle$ is the (unique up to scalar) $G$-invariant Hermitian form.

This is not true. The issue of realizability over $\mathbb R$ was fully addressed in Serre's Finite Groups: An Introduction. In particular, he gave the following smallest example (Section 8.9): $G=\{\pm1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$ be the quaternion group, and consider its 2-dimensional irreducible representation $\rho$. It's clear that the associated character $\chi$ is real, but this cannot be realized over $\mathbb R$.
To give a self-contained proof, if it can be realized over $\mathbb R$, then $\mathbb R$-algebra generated by the images of $\rho$ must be isomorphic to $M_{2}(\mathbb R)$. Note that $\dim \mathbb R[G]=\dim M_{2}(\mathbb R)$, we have $\rho$ induces an isomorphism $\mathbb R[G]\simeq \dim M_{2}(\mathbb R)$. But $\mathbb R[G]\simeq \mathbb H$ is a division ring, while $M_2(\mathbb R)$ is not.

The standard counter-example is $Q_8$: it has a character of degree $2$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$; but a representation corresponding to it is not realizable over $\mathbb{R}$. It is realizable over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, or more generally, it is realizable over a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ in which $-1$ can be written as sum of two squares. See Huppert-Character Theory of Finite Groups.
